# Array of functions that can be called like 'funs[1]();'

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, callback, function-pointers

I'm working on a Visual C++ 2010 Express console application.

Before I go into detail, the summary here is: How can I make an array/list/vector of functions and call them from that array?

So I'm having a little difficulty with function pointers. I'm writing a 'Terminal' class, which in turn has a member class 'CommandMap'. The purpose of the CommandMap class is to store a vector/array of functions and the strings that represent them in another vector/array. I want the functions to be called (only) when the class calls them from the vector, but it executed only when I added it to the vector and not when trying to call it.

I tried defining a type for it:

```
typedef void (*CmdCallback)();
```

I declared a vector to contain them:

```
vector<string> CmdNames;
vector<CmdCallback> CmdFuncs;
```

I add them like so:

```
// Map a new command
bool CommandMap::Map(string name, CmdCallback func)
{
    if (!IsNullOrSpace(name) && func != NULL)
    {
        if (!Exists(name))
        {
            CmdNames.push_back(name);
            CmdFuncs.push_back(func);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

And I try calling them like this:

```
// Get a command callback from its identifier
CmdCallback CommandMap::GetFunc(string name)
{
    int index = IndexOf(name);
    if (index == -1) return NULL;
    else return CmdFuncs.at(index);
}

// If the given string is a command indentifier
// it will invoke the associated callback.
bool CommandMap::Exec(string input)
{
    for each (string id in CmdStrings)
    {
        if (input == id)
        {
            CmdCallback cmd;
            cmd = GetFunc(id);
            cmd();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I tried using this:

```
CmdCallback SayHello()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return NULL; // Forces me to return null, guessing since it's
                 // not 'void' but a 'void' pointer it must return something
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    App = new Terminal(argc, argv);
    App->Commands->Map("say", SayHello);

    while (!App->ExecComplete)
    {
        App->WaitEnter();
        App->Commands->Exec("say");
        App->WaitEnter();
        App->ExecComplete = true;
    }

    return App->ExitCode;   
}
```

This works, at first. The function gets called when I try to `Map()` it though. And when I `Exec()` "say", it finds the callback, but when it tries to call it, I get this runtime error, to which I can see no detail other than the option to break or continue. The code it gives me is.

I pretty much want to abandon my method and try a new approach, maybe I'm going the wrong way with the void pointer typedef, and I need to throw a '&' or a '*' somewhere I haven't like in the `Map()` argument list. Maybe a vector isn't the best way to do this either.

Basically, I am asking how I can I make an array of functions that can (and only) be called by referencing them from the array. I'm terrible with callbacks.

Comment: Consider using `vector<pair<string, CmdCallback>>` or an `unordered_map<string, CmdCallback>` instead of two parallel vectors. Make sure your `cmd = GetFunc(id)` returns a non-null value before calling it.

Comment: You must learn something about function pointers. You can learn something from [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html). IF your functions are not static or are class memebers, you must also learn how to bind them, for example with boost::bind.

Comment: What exactly is your application intending to do which requires an array-of-functions?

Comment: @DCoder Thanks, I was unaware of making a vector of pairs and the unordered_map container, I'll have to look at the latter, but I don't much like using iterators, mainly due to my lack of knowledge about them.

Comment: @BenC Well it all works now :) But what this does is allows me to map a command string (ex. "exit") with a function (ex. ExitApp()) and so when I use `cin >> input;` I can check if the user entered that command, whatever command the user enters, it gets passed to `CommandMap->Exec(input)`, then it looks up the callback pertaining to that string, in this case the user enters "exit", gets passed to Exec(), and calls ExitApp(). Works like a charm now! Always wanted to programmatically parse user entered commands instead of using a switch() condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you actually want to declare `SayHello` as `void SayHello()` so that a pointer to `SayHello` has the type `void (*)()` (i.e. `CmdCallback`) which is what you need for your vector of functions.

Comment: Everybody else had very good advice, but you seem to have done the trick! Thank you! I thought I had to make the actual callback function of type 'CmdCallback', what I thought was a complicated problem was solved by basically only omitting a '*'. Strange I only got a runtime error and not a compiler error. Well thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [std::functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), or, if you don't have C++11 support, [boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/function.html). These are function object wrappers that can be easily constructed from free or member functions. You can store these in a standard library container or simple array.

Comment: I have VS2010 Express, which I heard has only some support for C++11. But I use Boost libraries and I think they're great. I will have to look at Boost.Function in the future, I read a bit about it. But had a bit of trouble wrapping my head around whether the boost::function you declare is a typedef for use with other functions or just an object that you can assign other functions to.

Comment: @BrandonMiller it is a callable object that you can initialize with various types of function. You can also assign to it.

Comment: So how could I call them from a container? I ask because it seems that whatever I add to the vector does not need to have a specific function signature. Or would I declare the vector like so?: `vector<std::function<void(int,char*)>> FuncList;`

Comment: @BrandonMiller right, the signature and return type determine the type of the function object, and you can only have one type in the container.